# Trying to Calculate Sheet Array

Tags: excel, vba

Is this gonna work?  How do I take proof that only the Array that I defined is calculated? I would like this macro to calculate only these Sheets to avoid lag/stutters, but I don't know how to prove whether it is calculating the entire workbook or is working with I would like.

```
Sub CALCULATE()
    Dim sheetsArray As Sheets
    Dim wBook As Workbook
    Set wBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sheetsArray = wBook.Sheets(Array("FORMULAS_A", "RECEITAS", "RECEITAS_DS"))

    Dim sheetObject As Worksheet

    For Each sheetObject In sheetsArray
        Calculate
    Next sheetObject
End Sub
```

Comment: `Calculate` ----> `sheetObject.Calculate`?

Comment: You can also easily test by setting a formula in a cell not part of your sheet array when calculation is set to manual and then running your code.

Comment: As @BigBen kind of mentioned - `Calculate` as you've put it is the same as `Application.Calculate` which will calculate all open workbooks.  You need to prefix it with the worksheet or range object for it to calculate just that.  [Application.Calculate method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.calculate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved, just changed as @BigBen comment:

```
For Each sheetObject In sheetsArray
   sheetObject.Calculate
Next sheetObject
```